# Does Freemarker 2.3.23 handle varargs properly?

Tags: java, freemarker

This (hideous; don't ask; I can't modify the data model or the configuration) expression doesn't work:

```
${statics["java.nio.file.Files"].write(statics["java.nio.file.Paths"].get("/foo/bar.stuff"), statics["java.nio.charset.Charset"].forName("UTF-8").encode(someStringContent).array(), enums["java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption"].WRITE)}
```

Model code:

```
    model.addAttribute("statics", new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23).build().getStaticModels());
    model.addAttribute("enums", new BeansWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23).build().getEnumModels());
```

Briefly, it is a (gross) way to take some Freemarker string content, turn it into a `byte[]` array, and write it to the `/foo/bar.stuff` path from within Freemarker.

The error indicates that Freemarker can't pick the proper varargs method:

```
Error executing FreeMarker template
FreeMarker template error:
When trying to call the non-varargs overloads:
No compatible overloaded variation was found; can't convert (unwrap) the 3rd argument to the desired Java type.
The FTL type of the argument values were: extended_hash+string (sun.nio.fs.UnixPath wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel), sequence (byte[] wrapped into f.t.DefaultArrayAdapter$ByteArrayAdapter), extended_hash+string (java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel).
When trying to call the varargs overloads:
Multiple compatible overloaded variations were found with the same priority.
The Java type of the argument values were: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath, byte[], java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.
The matching overload was searched among these members:
    static java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Path, Iterable, java.nio.file.OpenOption...),
    static java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Path, Iterable, java.nio.charset.Charset, java.nio.file.OpenOption...),
    static java.nio.file.Files.write(java.nio.file.Path, byte[], java.nio.file.OpenOption...)
```

I've tried other hacks, including creating an array of the proper type using `java.lang.reflect.Array#newInstance(Class, int)`, but that didn't help.

I'm assuming this is impossible?

Comment: Do you have access to the code where statics is defined? Could you paste it?

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm pasting the model code to get the error you see. Please correct it if it's not the same as yours.

Comment: Laird, is your statics BeanWrapper built with the EXPOSE_ALL exposure level?

Comment: Hi; thanks for your interest and help!  The code that stuffs things into the data model reads: `dataModel.put("statics", beansWrapper.getStaticModels());`  Tracing that back, `beansWrapper` is a subclass of `DefaultObjectWrapper` built using [the constructor that takes a `Version` as its only parameter](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/DefaultObjectWrapper.html#DefaultObjectWrapper-freemarker.template.Version-).  There doesn't appear to be a lot of magic in the subclass although it allows you to set custom `ModelFactory` instances.  These are not in play here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `statics` model field is built with `EXPOSE_ALL`, you could go deeper into the reflection rabbit hole:

```
<#assign class = statics["java.lang.Class"]>
<#assign openOptionClass = class.forName("java.nio.file.OpenOption")>
<#assign filesClass = class.forName("java.nio.file.Files")>
<#assign method = filesClass.getMethod("write", class.forName("java.nio.file.Path"),class.forName("[B"),class.forName("[Ljava.nio.file.OpenOption;"))>
<#assign path = statics["java.nio.file.Paths"].get("/foo/bar.stuff")>
<#assign utf8 = statics["java.nio.charset.Charset"].forName("UTF-8")>
<#assign writeOptions = enums["java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption"].WRITE>
<#assign writeOptionsArray = statics["java.lang.reflect.Array"].newInstance(openOptionClass,1)>
<#assign ignoreThisVoid = statics["java.lang.reflect.Array"].set(writeOptionsArray, 0, writeOptions)>
${method.invoke(null, path, utf8.encode(someStringContent).array(), writeOptionsArray)}
```

Or you could try a `PrintWriter` (still needs `EXPOSE_ALL`):

```
<#assign class = statics["java.lang.Class"]>
<#assign fileOutputStreamClass = class.forName("java.io.FileOutputStream")>
<#assign fileOutputStreamConstructor = fileOutputStreamClass.getConstructor(class.forName("java.lang.String"))>
<#assign fileOutputStream = fileOutputStreamConstructor.newInstance("/foo/bar.stuff")>
<#assign ignoreThisVoid = fileOutputStream.write(utf8.encode(someStringContent).array())>
```

Comment: So I didn't do this _exactly_, but it mirrors something that I _did_ do. I found that no matter what incantation that involves `java.lang.reflect.Array` (to "fake out" the vargars)—I found that no invocation of `java.lang.reflect.Array#newInstance(Class, int)` would work (Freemarker still got confused).

Comment: Ah, but your use of `getConstructor` is something for whatever reason I hadn't thought of!  That should get me out of this rabbit hole. :-) Thank you.

Comment: I tried both of these locally and they both worked for me

Comment: Sorry; I wasn't clear.  No combination of `Files#write()` in conjunction with `java.lang.reflect.Array#newInstance()` (to get the varargs parameter recognized) worked.  I haven't tried the reflection approach and assume (as you've shown) that it will work.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could you wrap the call to the `Files.write()` method in your own unambiguous method

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.OpenOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class UnambiugousMethodWrappers{
    public static Path writeBytes (Path path, byte[] bytes, OpenOption... options) throws IOException {
        return Files.write(path, bytes, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; for reasons that aren't really important here all I have at my disposal is the Freemarker template itself.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is going to be a glitch in overloaded method selection that's emulated for 100% backward compatibility. So you should increase the `incompatible_improvements` setting of your FreeMarker configuration to at least 2.3.21 for the fix to be activated (or if you aren't using the default for the `object_wrapper` setting, then the similar setting of the `ObjectWrapper` you are creating). But, you said you can't touch the FreeMarker configuration...

I have also seen in the other answer that you can't add your own static helper class either...

Comment: Indeed; I'm kind of hamstrung. :-)  Thanks for your help (and maintenance of Freemarker!).  It's certainly more flexible than any other template engine I've used.